# CountDownTimer doesn't works when the activity starts from a service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, countdowntimer, back-stack

I need to start an activity from a service when the device is locked. 
This activity has a CountDownTimer, when I start it from another activity and the device isn't locked all works, but when I try to start it from a Service when device is locked, the activity starts correctly but the CountDownTimer doesn't starts.

The activity with CountDownTimer that must start with device locked have this flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

and a simple CountDownTimer:

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
@Override onTick() and onFinish()
}
mCountDownTimer.start();
```

I start the mCountDownTimer in the activity's onCreate().

Service side, I must start this activity with:

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertActivity.class);
alertIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(alertIntent);
```

The activity starts, the device wake up but the mCountDownTimer don't starts.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you start your countDownTimer?

Comment: I start the countDownTimer in the activity's on Create().

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Comment: Is the onCreate method at least called? If not you can try onStart, onResume methods to start your timer. Even if you start with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag and your activity has singleTask or singleInstance configured in the manifest the new activity may be not created but the already created one brung to front.

Comment: @Kedarnath this is the code of entire activity http://nopaste.info/2748949c5a.html

Comment: @user527759 no singleTask or singleIstance configured in the manifest

Comment: are you able to view this `Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress" + progressValue + millisUntilFinished);` in DDMS ?

Comment: @user527759 I'm trying to start my CountDownTimer in the onResume() method of activity and it seems to work! Thanks you. Can you explain me why?
PS. How can I vote for your comment?

Comment: The problem of the onResume it will be called each time activity resumed which may be not good for you. If you need it to be run only once onCreate is a good place or you should control it from starting the second time in another way. You need to determine whether the onCreate is called or no when you start activity from Service. Put some logging there.

Comment: @user527759 If the activity starts normally (from another activity) and if it's started by a service the onCreate() method is called. In this second case (start by a service) the CountDownTimer starts only in onResume(). I can't understand why this behavior

Comment: That is weird. Can you see your log message "ALERT ACTIVITY ->> startcounter" in the LogCat when starting an activity?

Comment: @user527759 yes, so the onCreate() method it's called.

Comment: Maybe some exception occurs when onTick method is executed. Check you LogCat. Maybe you'll see releveant exception.

Comment: Nothing, for the moment I use it on onResum() method. Thanks you!